# How do I delete an Azure DevOps account I created by mistake?

Tags: azure-devops

I created an Azure DevOps account by mistake, pressing the wrong button.

How do I delete it?

Thanks.

Comment: OK.  Now I get it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you are talking about the **organizations** not account.

You account could create or be added in multiple organizations, for example:

[image]

If you do not have any account, to login in azure devops you need to [sign up for Azure DevOps with a personal Microsoft account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/sign-up-invite-teammates?view=azure-devops#sign-up-for-azure-devops-with-a-personal-microsoft-account)

[image]

This is actually a **Microsoft account**, if you do not want this account, you could [close it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12412/microsoft-account-how-to-close-account).

If you just not want the organization created by mistake, you should follow our detail step by step official tutorial-- [**Delete your organization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/delete-your-organization?view=azure-devops)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can go to the following url:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{ORGANIZATION_NAME}/_settings/
```

and you will have the delete organization button there:

[image: delete organization]

Comment: I wish I could rate this answer higher. No, go here and follow our tutorial BS, just straight forward, "here's how to do what you want to do" without any BS. brilliant, thanks.